# Filtering out warnings in poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara, poltergeist

I'm getting a specific warning in my specs (using poltergeist):

> Viewport argument key "minimal-ui" not recognized and ignored.

And it's 'poluting' my console. I thought I could filter it out by stubbing console.warn en console.info to an empty function. But it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my driver:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
    extensions: ['./spec/support/console.js'],
    phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'],
    timeout: 15
  })
end
```

and the extension:

```
(function () {
  var emptyFunction = function () {};

  // List from http://frugalcoder.us/post/2009/07/22/firebug_console_stub.aspx
  window.console = {
    log: emptyFunction,
    debug: emptyFunction,
    info: emptyFunction,
    warn: emptyFunction,
    error: emptyFunction,
    assert: emptyFunction,
    dir: emptyFunction,
    dirxml: emptyFunction,
    trace: emptyFunction,
    group: emptyFunction,
    groupCollapsed: emptyFunction,
    groupEnd: emptyFunction,
    time: emptyFunction,
    timeEnd: emptyFunction,
    profile: emptyFunction,
    profileEnd: emptyFunction,
    count: emptyFunction
  };
}());
```

Any idea what's throwing this and how I could quiet it down?

Comment: does you layout contains the metatag `<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui">`?

Comment: Yes this is in the layout as intended. I'm just curious how to get this out of my terminal. What method does the browser use to show this in the console, so I can stub it out.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this this still relevant, but I ran into this today as well. If you want to suppress all output from `console.log`, you could do

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(
    app,
    phantomjs_logger: File.open(File::NULL, 'w'),
  )
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try suppressing errors in your env.rb:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    options = {
        :js_errors => false,
        :debug => false,
        :phantomjs_options => ['--load-images=no', '--disk-cache=false'],
        :inspector => true,
    }
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```